# Ambiguous reference to member 'delegate'

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

I'm trying to create an instance of a singleton class written in Objective-C. I must conform to it's delegate protocol. The Swift implementation looks something like this:

```
class SomeClass: ManagerDelegate {
  let manager = Manager.sharedInstance()

  func someFunction(){
    manager.delegate = self
  }
}
```

The Objective-C singleton class looks something like this:

```
// header
@protocol ManagerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)delegateMethod;
@end

@interface Manager : NSObject {

}
+ (id)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@end


// class file
+ (id) sharedManager{
  static Manager *theSharedManager = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    theSharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
  });

  return theSharedManager;
}

- (void) someInternalMethod{
  [delegate delegateMethod];
}
```

Upon specifying the delegate (`manager.delegate = self`), I receive the error

> Ambiguous reference to member 'delegate'

Is the Objective-C class improperly formed or am I implementing it incorrectly? Am I missing something else?

Comment: You say "The Objective-C singleton class looks something like this"; Does the singleton only inherit from `NSObject` or does it inherit from some other object too?

Comment: I setup a test which only inherits from NSObject and still receive the ambiguous reference error.

Comment: I don't know if this will help the problem with the Swift code but the `delegate` property in the Objective-C class should be declared as `@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ManagerDelegate> delegate;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the definition of your `sharedInstance` method in Objective-C.  By declaring it as

```
+ (id)sharedInstance;
```

it gets converted to sharedInstance() -> AnyObject! in Swift.  Swift then doesn't know which of many potential `delegate` properties that it can find you mean.  If you change your Objective C declaration and implementation to be:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
```

your problem will go away.

And as @rmaddy points out, your delegate should be `weak` not `assign`.  If you use `assign` then `delegate` will be left as an invalid pointer in the event that the delegate is deallocated.

Also, the use of a delegate with a singleton is a bit contradictory.  Given that you will only ever have one instance of the `Manager` which may be used by a number of other objects and you can only have one active delegate at a time there is the potential for conflicts.

I would suggest that either blocks/closures or `NSNotification` is a better approach to call backs from a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Its because whenever you bring instance from objective c code to swift it gives as AnyObject so

```
let manager = Manager.sharedInstance() //manager is AnyObject due to bridging between objc and swift
```

gives you AnyObject for manager property. You need to forcefully cast that AnyObject to Manager to use it as manager's instance like below.

```
class SomeClass: NSObject, ManagerDelegate {
    let manager = Manager.sharedInstance() as! Manager //here was your error

    func someFunction(){
        manager.delegate = self
    }
    func delegateMethod() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Wouldn't this be fixed if the Objective-C code properly declared `sharedInstance` to return `instancetype` instead of `id`?

Comment: yeah, great. it will solve it too. I don't know objective-c, so i gave the solution what I could understand from swift.